# Windows Server Web Application Load Balancer - How to check whether it is using Sticky Session or Round Robin?

Tags: windows, load-balancing

I have Web application load balancer config in Windows as below for my server , I am not able to figure it out whether it is using Sticky Session or Round Robin ? Ay help is appreciated.

Config file :

```
**  Virtual Server - abc-e1-vip-443  **
ltm virtual /Common/abc-e1-vip-443 {
    description 2000111111
    destination /Common/100.100.100.100:443
    ip-protocol tcp
    mask 255.255.255.255
    persist {
        /Common/source_addr {
            default yes
        }
    }
    pool /Common/abc-e1-vip-443
    profiles {
        /Common/abc-serverssl-no-retain {
            context serverside
        }
        /Common/gaits-e1-05-15-2020 {
            context clientside
        }
        /Common/http { }
        /Common/http2 { }
        /Common/wom-tcp-wan-optimized { }
    }
    rules {
        /Common/abc-e1-10-04-2019
    }
    serverssl-use-sni disabled
    source 0.0.0.0/0
    source-address-translation {
        type automap
    }
    translate-address enabled
    translate-port enabled
}

**  LTM Pool - abc-e1-vip-443  **
ltm pool /Common/abc-e1-vip-443 {
    load-balancing-mode least-connections-member
    members {
        /Common/111.23.45.67:443 {
            address 111.23.45.67
        }
        /Common/111.23.45.67:443 {
            address 111.23.45.67
            session user-disabled
        }
    }
    monitor /Common/tcp
}

**  LTM Monitor - tcp  **
ltm monitor tcp tcp {
    defaults-from none
    destination *:*
    interval 5
    ip-dscp 0
    manual-resume disabled
    recv none
    recv-disable none
    reverse disabled
    send none
    time-until-up 0
    timeout 16
    transparent disabled
    up-interval 0
}

**  Profile - abc-serverssl-no-retain  **
ltm profile server-ssl /Common/abc-serverssl-no-retain {
    app-service none
    defaults-from /Common/serverssl
    retain-certificate false
}

**  Profile - abc-e1-05-15-2020  **
ltm profile client-ssl /Common/abc-e1-05-15-2020 {
    app-service none
    cert /Common/abc-e1-05-15-2020.crt
    cert-key-chain {
        abc-e1-05-15-2020_abc-e1-05-15-2020-INT {
            cert /Common/abc-e1-05-15-2020.crt
            chain /Common/abc-e1-05-15-2020-INT.crt
            key /Common/abc-e1-05-15-2020.key
            passphrase $M$l4$/YxgwM6v1PJ/wTItRnf+KA==
        }
    }
    chain /Common/abc-e1-05-15-2020-INT.crt
    defaults-from /Common/clientssl-secured-07-30-2018
    inherit-ca-certkeychain true
    inherit-certkeychain false
    key /Common/abc-e1-05-15-2020.key
    passphrase $M$Ds$OlVzBsx5N4ZUkx4qkOCmjQ==
    renegotiation disabled
}

**  Profile - http2  **
ltm profile http2 http2 {
    connection-idle-timeout 300
    insert-header disabled
    insert-header-name X-HTTP2
    enforce-tls-requirements enabled
    include-content-length disabled
    activation-modes { alpn }
    concurrent-streams-per-connection 10
    receive-window 32
    frame-size 2048
    write-size 16384
    header-table-size 4096
}

**  Profile - http  **
ltm profile http http {
    basic-auth-realm none
    lws-width 80
    oneconnect-transformations enabled
    oneconnect-status-reuse "200 206"
    proxy-type reverse
    enforcement {
        max-header-count 64
        max-header-size 32768
        pipeline allow
        unknown-method allow
    }
    request-chunking sustain
    response-chunking sustain
}

**  Profile - wom-tcp-wan-optimized  **
ltm profile tcp wom-tcp-wan-optimized {
    defaults-from /Common/tcp-wan-optimized
    delayed-acks disabled
    idle-timeout 600
    nagle enabled
    proxy-buffer-high 196608
    proxy-buffer-low 131072
    proxy-mss enabled
    receive-window-size 458752
    selective-nack enabled
    send-buffer-size 458752
    slow-start disabled
    zero-window-timeout 300000
    pkt-loss-ignore-burst 8
    pkt-loss-ignore-rate 10000
}

**  LTM iRule - gaits-e1-10-04-2019  **
ltm rule /Common/gaits-e1-10-04-2019 {
when HTTP_REQUEST {
    log local0. "version is [HTTP::version] and uri is [HTTP::uri]"
        switch -glob [HTTP::path] {
            "/SSRSReports*" { 
                node 111.23.45.67 443
            } default {
                pool abc-e1-vip-443
            }
        }
    }
}

**  LTM Persistence - source_addr  **
ltm persistence source-addr source_addr {
    map-proxies enabled
    mask none
    mirror disabled
    timeout 180
}
```

Answer (score 0):

source-address persistence, which would probably understand as sticky session.The block below show the same.

```
**  LTM Persistence - source_addr  **
ltm persistence source-addr source_addr {
    map-proxies enabled
    mask none
    mirror disabled
    timeout 180
}
```